# Huawei default mail app blocks http deeplinks

Tags: android, deep-linking, huawei-developers

i am facing an issue with the default Email app on huawei devices, it opens http scheme inside a browser preview and prevent my app to handle it.
more details:
here what i have in my manifest

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="exemple.com" android:scheme="https"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

of course on other devices when click on the link from the email app the chooser is opened to propose my app & a browser. but with the default email app on huawei it opens the link directly in a browser preview preventing the android system to handle the intent and blocks the chooser.
[image]

Comment: There is no requirement for any email app to display links in an external Web browser.

Comment: actually it's not external web browser. it's a preview inside the email app (i updated with a screenshot)

Comment: I understand that. Any email app is welcome to do what it wants.

Comment: well i found this really strange to force users where to open there links.
so if i understand well there is now way to change this behaviour and make the chooser appears with compatible apps

Comment: There might be a setting within the Huawei email app that controls this behavior.